# Customize forms option not present in Sharepoint list PowerApps dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, list-form, powerapps-forms

The closest question I could find to my sitionation is here, however the answers do not solve my issue [Customize forms option (PowerApps) not showing up in SharePoint Online List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271566/customize-forms-option-powerapps-not-showing-up-in-sharepoint-online-list)

I am working with Sharepoint online, Win 10, MS Edge. I have a list named "Sales Contacts", the list columns were created from core site columns group "Core Contact and Calendar Columns".

I tried the save as list template suggestion and you can see that in both the original and test list the same result. 
[image: pa no form1]
[image: pa no form2]

Any additional suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom forms for lists are only supported in generic lists and generic document libraries. Custom list and library templates are currently not supported; including but not limited to lists such as Announcements, Contacts and Tasks.

Please ensure the list template is custom list and not Contacts as shown below:

[image]
[image]

References:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-sharepoint-online#known-issues

Comment: Thank you @Julie_MSFT, this solved my issue. I recreated the list as a Custom List using the "Core Contact and Calendar Columns" fields and the "Customize forms" now appears. Very much appreciate the help.